# How to compare multiple records in multiple rows for the same ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

Problem: I'm trying to see, per classID, if an employee (empID) has at least 1 StateCertArea in the FedCertArea, and flag = 1 if so.

Background knowledge on this fake case:

- All classID's have FederalCertAreas
- All employee's have StateCertAreas
- I'm trying to see if an employee has a StateCertArea that matches any FedCertArea for the ClassID.

I need to avoid a SELECT in a CASE statement if possible.  Maybe using some temp tables and a join, but I'll take the help I can get.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temptable
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( ClassID int, EmpID decimal(10,0), StateCertArea varchar(4), FedCertArea varchar(4))

INSERT INTO #temptable (ClassID, EmpID, StateCertArea, FedCertArea)
VALUES
( 572888, 77777, '228', '228'),
( 572888, 77777, '389', '389'),
( 572888, 77777, '374', '374'),
( 222555, 77777, '333', '999')

SELECT t.ClassID
     , t.EmpID
     , t.StateCertArea
     , t.FedCertArea      
     --, CASE WHEN 'EmployeeID has at least 1 StateCertArea in FedCertArea' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsInArea    
FROM #temptable AS t
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: for example provided would you please show what result you expecting.
are you looking for something like this: [add to select statement as another column] , CASE WHEN t2.StateCertificationArea = t3.FederalCertificationArea THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS testresunt

Comment: Can you also specify the expected result, i.e. complete the [mcve].

Comment: select case when exists(select 1 from somearea sa where sa.areaid = yourtable.areaid) then 1 else 0 end as exist, ...

Comment: I added the expected result and some additional code to show what I'd like to happen if the employeeID was not certified in area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `outer apply` provides an efficient way to run correlated subqueries such as the one needed here e.g:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temptable
CREATE TABLE #temptable (ClassID int, EmpID decimal(10,0), StateCertArea varchar(4), FedCertArea varchar(4))

INSERT INTO #temptable (ClassID, EmpID, StateCertArea, FedCertArea)
VALUES
( 572888, 77777, '228', '228'),
( 572888, 77777, '389', '389'),
( 572888, 77777, '374', '374'),
( 222555, 77777, '333', '999')

SELECT DISTINCT
       t.ClassID
     , t.EmpID
     , CASE WHEN oa.HasMatchingArea = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsInArea    
FROM #temptable AS t
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP(1) 1 AS HasMatchingArea
   FROM #temptable AS t2
   WHERE t2.ClassID = t.ClassID
     AND t2.EmpID = t.EmpID
     AND t2.StateCertArea = t.FedCertArea
) AS oa
```

| ClassID | EmpID | IsInArea |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222555 | 77777 | 0 |
| 572888 | 77777 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n9tQQRJH)

**alternate** using `coalesce`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t.ClassID
     , t.EmpID
     , COALESCE(oa.HasMatchingArea,0) AS IsInArea    
FROM #temptable AS t
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP(1) 1 AS HasMatchingArea
   FROM #temptable AS t2
   WHERE t2.ClassID = t.ClassID
     AND t2.EmpID = t.EmpID
     AND t2.StateCertArea = t.FedCertArea
) AS oa
```

Comment: This worked well thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to avoid a SELECT in a CASE statement if possible.

How about a CASE in a SELECT?

```
SELECT ClassID, EmpID, MAX(CASE WHEN StateCertArea = FedCertArea THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IsInArea
FROM #temptable
GROUP BY ClassID, EmpID
```

It's called **conditional aggregation**. I generally performs okay and it at least works on the sample data:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/y5CKgHgJ

... though it's not clear what you want to happen if you had these rows:

| ClassID | EmpID | StateCertArea | FedCertArea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 432818 | 77777 | 228 | 114 |
| 432818 | 77777 | 114 | 366 |

The above SQL would give the `IsInArea` column a `0` value, but it's possible you'd want a `1` here.